# Add a boundary circle around amCharts4 Gauge chart

Tags: reactjs, amcharts4

I am new to amCharts. I am using amCharts4 to create a SpeedMeter kind of Gauge using amCharts and React.
I am not able to add a surrounding circle around the Gauge. I tried adding circle object to chart plotContainer and radarContainer but it didn't work.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
import * as am4charts from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';

function GaugeChart1() {
    useEffect(() => {
        let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv1", am4charts.GaugeChart);

        // Create axis
        let xAxes1 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        xAxes1.min = -10;
        xAxes1.max = 10;
        xAxes1.strictMinMax = true;
        xAxes1.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
        xAxes1.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

        // Set the 'inside' property to true to move labels closer to the chart
        xAxes1.renderer.labels.template.padding(20,20,20,20);*/
        xAxes1.renderer.labels.template.padding(-10,-10,-10,-10);

        // Add ranges to the axis
        let range1 = xAxes1.axisRanges.create();
        range1.value = -10;
        range1.endValue = 0;
        range1.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
        range1.axisFill.fill = am4core.color('#075703');

        let range2 = xAxes1.axisRanges.create();
        range2.value = 0;
        range2.endValue = 10;
        range2.axisFill.fillOpacity = 1;
        range2.axisFill.fill = am4core.color('#FF0F03');

        // Add a needle
        let hand = chart.hands.push(new am4charts.ClockHand());
        hand.fill = am4core.color('#464646');
        hand.stroke = am4core.color('#cccccc');
        hand.axis = xAxes1;
        hand.pin.radius = 50;
        hand.value = 0;

        chart.startAngle = -224;
        chart.innerRadius = "80%";
        chart.endAngle = 45;

        return () => {
            chart.dispose(); // Clean up the chart when component unmounts
        };
    }, []);

    return <div id="chartdiv1" style={{width: '400px', height: '400px'}}></div>;
}

export default GaugeChart1;
```

[image]